# OpenGL direct state access extension is not supported

Tags: opengl, display-driver

I am trying to run Vega Prime 5 and when I run active preview i got the following message:"OpenGL direct state access extension is not supported with current hardware and/or driver setup". Despite that it says the error is fatal, active preview runs fine, however the image is somehow "bad quality". It's kind of dark and has few colors, shadows do not render properly and so on. All this maybe unimportant. My graphics card is ATI Radeone HD 6670. I assume it should support this extension. I updated and reinstalled my drivers.

My main question is where to look for this extension. Please point out where to look if this extension is not supported by hardware or driver setup. Where do I check it and possibly enable the support?

I checked in the OpenGL Extensions Viewer and the GL_EXT_direct_state_access doesnt seem to be supported (It's displayed in white, instead of green). Howevere ATI Radeone HD 6670 seems to support this extension. I am confused. Can I somehow enable the support?

I got a suggestion that it's a driver problem, any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the white and the green circles mean that the extension *IS* supported. Green means that it's part of the OpenGL core (which it isn't).

So, my guess would be that either the application can't detect this extension correctly (contact the author of that app), OR you have some sort of dual GPU configuration with Intel's HD GPU (which DON'T support this) and the application is trying to run on the Intel's GPU instead of the Radeon one (consult an advanced user and ask him to force the app to run on Radeon).

Have a nice day!

Comment: I've been told that this application doesn't support ATI graphics that well, only Nvidia, so I left it at that. Thanks for clarifying the points of interest here.